# Django CreateView with ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django

I want to add a phone number to a person.

My `models.py` contains:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Phone(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'personal'),
        ('C', 'company')
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
```

My `views.py` contains:

```
class PersonCreate(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'description']

class PhoneCreate(CreateView):
    model = Phone
    fields = '__all__'
```

My `urls.py` contains:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PersonDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/addPhone$', PhoneCreate.as_view(), 
     name='phone_create')
```

Now it works like this:
I am entering `Person` detail view (url: 'detail'). Here I have an `Add Address` button that redirects me to view (url: 'phone_create'), but I still have to choose person. How to create phone number to person from detail view automatically?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the correct answer:

```
class PhoneCreate(CreateView):
    model = Phone
    fields = ['number', 'type']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.person_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(PhoneCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```